# Is there a way to specify the encoding of a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

Is there a way to mark the encoding of a PowerShell script *within* the script (much like Perl's `use utf8`)?

When googling about that, I only find recommendations that change the default encoding globally or for the session which is not what I want or need because I have a script that contains utf-8 strings and I want to make sure that they're treated or understood as such.

If this is not possible, I'd like to specify the encoding of the script at the time when I execute it.

Comment: Powershell gets the encoding based on either the BOM set on the file or through the default settings. The only way to change this only for certain scripts perhaps would be to change the global encoding in the script and return it to its original state at the end of the script. Though this is just a guess.